# How to make my bot give send messages permissions to the specified role id , when prompted "=heist roleid"

Tags: discord, discord.js

I've made a discord bot and made a function in which it unlocks the channel for the members role which is appointed to everyone in my server. I want to make it so that it requires the id that is going to be unlocked after writing its id so basically `=heist roleid`.
I want this to unlock the channel **only** for the given role.

My current code:

```
  const Discord = require("discord.js");
  const client = new Discord.Client();
  const prefix = ('=')
  var numeral = require('numeral');
  client.once('ready', () => {
     console.log('Dank heists is now online');
     client.user.setPresence({
      activity: {
        type:"PLAYING",
        name: "discord.io/heists",
        status: "available",
        }   
      });
  }); 
else if (message.content.startsWith(prefix +'heist' )) {
      message.channel.createOverwrite("793930139737128997", {
        SEND_MESSAGES: true
      })
        .then(channel => console.log(channel.permissionOverwrites.get(message.author.id)))
        .catch(console.error);
      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('HEIST HAS NOW STARTED!!!')
      .setThumbnail('https://img2.pngio.com/unlocked-padlock-png-transparent-unlocked-padlockpng-images-lock-unlock-png-512_512.png')
      .setColor('#1d35cf')
      .setFooter('Manan, ')
      .setDescription(" I HAVE UNLOCKED THIS CHANNEL SO PEOPLE CAN JOIN THE HEIST " )
     
      message.channel.send(embed)
    }
```

update and send the whole code all together if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to learn JavaScript first and then learn the basics of Discord.js and Node.js.

Answer to your question :

```js
else if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "heist")) {
    const roleT = message.content.replace(prefix + "heist", "").trim();
    const role = message.guild.roles.cache
        .filter((r) => r.name.toLowerCase() === roleT.toLowerCase())
        .first();

    if (!role) {
        return message.channel.send("Please tag a role!");
    }

    message.channel
        .createOverwrite(role.id, {
            SEND_MESSAGES: true,
        })
        .then((channel) =>
            console.log(channel.permissionOverwrites.get(message.author.id))
        )
        .catch(console.error);
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("HEIST HAS NOW STARTED!!!")
        .setThumbnail(
            "https://img2.pngio.com/unlocked-padlock-png-transparent-unlocked-padlockpng-images-lock-unlock-png-512_512.png"
        )
        .setColor("#1d35cf")
        .setFooter("Manan, ")
        .setDescription(
            " I HAVE UNLOCKED THIS CHANNEL SO PEOPLE CAN JOIN THE HEIST "
        );

    message.channel.send(embed);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help. i replaced it and now it works yay!